# Crystal - add running total field from subreport

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, db2

I have a Crystal Report that lists information by item number based on selection criteria and includes sum of ordered quantity.  Since I don't know how to do a nested query to a DB2 database in Crystal, I created a sub-report to total quantity on hand by item number.  How do I get the total of the quantity on hand from the sub-report into the main report where the item numbers match?

I do have a left join between F4211 and F41021 on F4211.SDITM=F41021.LIITM.

Data selection for main report.

```
{F4211.SDNXTR} < "999" and
{F4211.SDUORG} <> 0.00 and
{F4211.SDAN8} = 200038.00 and
{F4211.SDLNTY} = "S" and
{F4211.SDDCTO} = "SO" and
{F4211.SDSOBK} >= 0.00
```

Data Selection for sub-report

```
{F41021.LILOTS} = "" and
{F41021.LIPQOH} > 0.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass Shared variables from a subreport to a main report. 
- define the variable in the main report 
WhilePrintingRecords; 
 Shared NumberVar *variable*;
  *variable*
- assign a value to the variable in your subreport
Shared NumberVar *variable*;
  *variable*:= sum({*data.field*})
- use in other formulas or as needed in the main report

Would it be better to have data you are putting in the subreport just become part of a details section in the main report that is hidden? Then you can put summary fields in the other groups as needed.

Comment: How do I get the subtotal for the on-hand item from the sub-report into the main report where the item numbers match?

Comment: If you just need to display the subtotal on the main report, you can modify the subreport layout by hiding sections, resizing, etc. until only the subtotal is the only thing that displays on the main report. You can't use the subtotal in summaries or calculations on the main report without using the variable. Did you need to link the subreport to the main report by linking them on a common field?

Comment: Jackpot!  I had to dig around but you pointed me in the right direction.  Thank you so much for the feedback, I couldn't have finished this without your assistance.